# Create a new indexed column with only year and month VS index datetime/timestamp column directly

Tags: mysql, datetime, indexing

The problem is that I need to maintain a large table with about hundreds of millions of rows, and I need to query the data base on year and month.
Will it get a better performance if I created a new column with only year and month like 1906(unsigned small int) instead of create an index base on the timestamp/datetime column directly (precision of seconds, like "2019-06-03 11:22")?

And will it decrease the index size?

Comment: You can add `DATE` column, fill it in with triggers and create index. DATE will use 3 bytes as smallint + tinyint that you'd use for storing year and month so performance would be the same. This would require a bit more for storage that YYMM format you mentioned.

Comment: I need to clarify: DATE -- 3 bytes. YYYY + MM (two columns as I thought at the beginning) -- 3 bytes. YYMM (one column as you mentioned) -- 2 bytes. TIMESTAMP -- 4 bytes. I'd go for DATE. Not as compact as YYMM but standard type that easy to understand and to work with.

Comment: @fifonik, OK, I see, and `date` type will be better due to the precision compared to `YYMM`. BTW, do you know that will I get benefit from the decreasing of the number of unique values in the index column?

Comment: If the query you are trying to optimize prematurely would be selecting all on exact month, then going with YYMM index would be better as it would 'const' vs 'range'. So I would not do anything like this from the beginning. I'd index TIMESTAMP/DATETIME column you already have. If you face performance issues -- you will see on the real queries that causing troubles and optimize them.

Comment: I feel like you could test the hypothesis

Comment: @Strawberry, I generated 14 million rows of data and tested it (posted as an answer), however I don't know why it's the result.

Comment: What version are you using?  Newer versions have "generated" columns.

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.7 installed from Ubuntu repository, I googled generated column just now, however I can not use funtions for newer than MySQL 5.6, as the MySQL of our production environment is 5.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... data warehouse of which the data is updated every night... And most of the data is used for statistics by date or by week/ month

In that case, you are asking the wrong question.  The 'real' question is how to get daily/weekly/monthly stats from a Data Wherehouse efficiently.  The answer is to build and maintain Summary Table(s).

Since you are loading a day's worth of new data each night (if I interpret your statement correctly), then that is an excellent time to summarize the data for the one day and populate rows in a summary table.  Such a table might have only one-tenth as many rows, and can be indexed in multiple rows.  Then displaying statistics can sum up the daily subtotals to get a week/month/arbitrary-date-range quite efficiently.  Such a table would have a `DATE` column.  This is not the best according to Chen's research, but it is clearer and easier to work with than some form of int.  More importantly, it is probably a tiny percentage of the total time taken.  And the Summary Table will be much smaller, so a byte or two (in the size of the date column) won't matter compared to total disk space consumed.

More discussion of [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

Comment: "data is updated every night" -- This Answer assumes you mean "INSERTed", not "UPDATEd".

Answer (score 1):

I generated 14 million rows of data and tested with flowing procedure, I don't know how to explain the result, however it is the result.

## Platform

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04 (virtual machine)
MySQL: 5.7
```

## Test Result

time consumed to execute the query

```
index           data type          sample data    max     min      avg
int3          | int(3)   |            20170902| 0.248|  0.169|  0.1946
int10         | int(10)  |              201709| 0.248|  0.183|  0.2016
smallint      | smallint |                1709| 0.306|  0.182|  0.2114
int4          | int(4)   |              201709| 0.325|  0.175|  0.2138
date          | date     |          2017-09-02| 0.397|  0.242|  0.2772
datetime_date | datetime | 2017-09-02 00:00:00| 0.422|  0.278|  0.3108
datetime      | datetime | 2017-09-02 05:00:01| 0.437|  0.279|  0.3142
timestamp     | timestamp| 2017-09-02 05:00:01| 0.96 |   0.79|  0.8306
timestamp_date| timestamp| 2017-09-02 00:00:00| 0.978|  0.792|  0.8392
```

## Table Structure

```
DROP TABLE `datetime_index_test`;
CREATE TABLE `datetime_index_test` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`datetime` datetime NULL,
`datetime_date` datetime NULL,
`timestamp` timestamp NULL,
`timestamp_date` timestamp NULL,
`smallint` smallint unsigned NULL,
`int10` int(10) unsigned NULL,
`int4` int(4) unsigned NULL,
`int3` int(3) unsigned NULL,
`date` date NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `idx_datetime` (`datetime`),
KEY `idx_datetime_date` (`datetime_date`),
KEY `idx_timestamp` (`timestamp`),
KEY `idx_timestamp_date` (`timestamp_date`),
KEY `idx_smallint` (`smallint`),
KEY `idx_int10` (`int10`),
KEY `idx_int4` (`int4`),
KEY `idx_int3` (`int3`),
KEY `idx_date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

## Sample Data

```
             datetime            timestamp  smallint   int10    int4      int3        date  datetime_date  timestamp_date
  2017-09-01 00:17:50| 2017-09-01 00:17:50|     1709| 201709| 201709| 20170901| 2017-09-01|    2017-09-01|     2017-09-01
  2017-09-01 01:03:53| 2017-09-01 01:03:53|     1709| 201709| 201709| 20170901| 2017-09-01|    2017-09-01|     2017-09-01
  2017-09-01 02:29:56| 2017-09-01 02:29:56|     1709| 201709| 201709| 20170901| 2017-09-01|    2017-09-01|     2017-09-01
  2017-09-01 03:15:05| 2017-09-01 03:15:05|     1709| 201709| 201709| 20170901| 2017-09-01|    2017-09-01|     2017-09-01
  2017-09-01 04:22:50| 2017-09-01 04:22:50|     1709| 201709| 201709| 20170901| 2017-09-01|    2017-09-01|     2017-09-01
  2017-09-01 05:07:05| 2017-09-01 05:07:05|     1709| 201709| 201709| 20170901| 2017-09-01|    2017-09-01|     2017-09-01
  2017-09-01 06:41:12| 2017-09-01 06:41:12|     1709| 201709| 201709| 20170901| 2017-09-01|    2017-09-01|     2017-09-01
```

## SQL command

```
Index: int3
SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `datetime_index_test` WHERE `int3`>=20180601 AND `int3`<20180701;

Index: int10
SQL: select count(*) from `datetime_index_test` where `int10`>=201806 and `int10`<201807;

Index: smallint
SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `datetime_index_test` WHERE `smallint`>=1806 AND `smallint`<1807;

Index: int4
SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `datetime_index_test` WHERE `int4`>=201806 AND `int4`<201807;

Index: date
SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `datetime_index_test` WHERE `date`>="2018-06-01 00:00" AND `date`<"2018-07-01 00:00";

Index: datetime_date
SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `datetime_index_test` WHERE `datetime_date`>="2018-06-01 00:00" AND `datetime_date`<"2018-07-01 00:00";

Index: datetime
SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `datetime_index_test` WHERE `datetime`>="2018-06-01 00:00" AND `datetime`<"2018-07-01 00:00";

Index: timestamp
SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `datetime_index_test` WHERE `timestamp`>="2018-06-01 00:00" AND `timestamp`<"2018-07-01 00:00";

Index: timestamp_date
SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `datetime_index_test` WHERE `timestamp_date`>="2018-06-01 00:00" AND `timestamp_date`<"2018-07-01 00:00";
```

## Python code to generate the sample data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.date_range(start="2017-09-01 00:00", end="2019-05-01 00:00", freq='h').rename('datetime').to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
df = pd.concat([df]*1000, axis=0)
arr = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3600, size=(len(df))) 
arr = arr*np.timedelta64(1, 's')
df['datetime'] = df['datetime']+ arr
df = df.sort_values(['datetime'])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df['timestamp'] = df['datetime']
df['smallint'] = df['timestamp'].dt.year-2000
df['smallint'] = df['smallint']*100
df['smallint'] = df['timestamp'].dt.month + df['smallint']
df['int10'] = df['smallint']+ 200000
df['int4'] = df['int10']
df['int3'] = df['int4']*100 + df['datetime'].dt.day
df['date'] = df['timestamp'].dt.date
df['datetime_date'] = df['date']
df['timestamp_date'] = df['date']
```

Comment: Interesting -- I wonder why `TIMESTAMP` is so much slower than `DATETIME`.

Comment: What version of MySQL (or MariaDB) was this tested against?  There was a change in `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` formats at some point in history.  Since it involved changing the size, it should be relevant.

Comment: Hi, @Rick James, I'm using MySQL 5.7 installed from Ubuntu repository. I heared that timestamp may have better performance, however the test result really confused me.

Comment: Nice research.  `DATETIME` used to be an 8-byte packed decimal; `TIMESTAMP` was 4 bytes.  Now (5.6?) they start with 5 bytes, including a length indication for number of fractional seconds.  Probably this is why you found that ints were faster than _those_ datatypes.  I can't explain the other discrepancies that you found.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and Yes.  Smaller amount of data in the column and the index will be faster.

Comment: Thank you @Programnik, do you mean that smaller data type is better, or that I will get benefit from the decreasing of the number of unique values in the index column?

Comment: Yes, but...  Is it smaller enough to be worth the effort?  And will the extra overhead outweigh the benefits?

Comment: @Rick James, I'm trying to design the data structure of a data warehouse of which the data is updated every night, so the write performance is less important than read performance, So if what I tried will benefit for read performance, I wanna have a try. And most of the data is used for statistics by date or by week/ month. If I save the data as int, 2 bytes may be enough.